# multiselect.js compatibility with older jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, compatibility, backwards-compatibility, jquery-ui-multiselect

The stated minimum level of compatibility of the [multiselect.js](http://loudev.com/) jQuery library is with **jQuery 1.8+**

I'm wondering what part of the codebase causes this dependency and what could I do to make the script more backwards compatible.

For instance,  when [I try it with 1.3.2](http://jsbin.com/uhERisi/1), the script breaks on 'split' function, called from within the 'each' function:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'split' of undefined jquery-1.3.2.min.js:12
o.fn.extend.data     jquery-1.3.2.min.js:12
(anonymous function) jquery.multi-select.js:481
o.extend.each        jquery-1.3.2.min.js:12
o.fn.o.each          jquery-1.3.2.min.js:12
$.fn.multiSelect     jquery.multi-select.js:478
```

This section of code is what is causing the breakage:

```
return this.each(function () {  // this line
  var $this = $(this),
      data = $this.data('multiselect'),
      options = $.extend({}, $.fn.multiSelect.defaults, $this.data(), typeof option === 'object' && option);

  if (!data){ $this.data('multiselect', (data = new MultiSelect(this, options))); }

  if (typeof option === 'string'){
    data[option](args[1]);
  } else {
    data.init();
  }
});
```

Comment: Any reason to not upgrade instead?

Comment: the line that's causing the problem: options = $.extend({}, $.fn.multiSelect.defaults, $this.data(), typeof option === 'object' && option);

Comment: The reason for not upgrading is because it is a large legacy project with zero automated tests and many other script dependencies.  Upgrading jQuery for this script will cause a knock-on effect for other scripts where unwanted compatibility issues will appear.  The level of effort upgrade and test the entire site to get one single select form widget to look better is unfortunately out of the question.